When does $n$ divide $u_n$ if $u_1=1$, $u_n=(n-1)u_{n-1}+1$?
I'm working through the Background section to 'The Mathematical Olympiad Handbook' by A. Gardiner, OUP, 1997, and this appears on page 17:

(***) Let $u_1=1$, $u_n=(n-1)u_{n-1}+1$. For which values of $n$ is $u_n$ divisible by $n$?
When you think you know, try to give a proper proof that your answer is correct.

I've not been able to come up with an answer - can anyone help?
For info, the first few values of $u_n$ are $1$, $2$, $5$, $16$, $65$, $326$, $1957$, $13700$, $109601$, $986410$, $9864101$, $108505112$, $1302061345$, $16926797486$,$\ldots$ and so the first few values of $n$ for which $n$ divides $u_n$ are $1$, $2$, $4$, $5$, $10$, $13$, $\ldots$.
Is there an obvious pattern to this?

Wolfram Alpha gives no nice general value of $u(n)$ , only $u(n)=e\gamma(n,1)$ where $\gamma(n,1)$ is the incomplete gamme function. Inspecting further solutions , I cannot spot any pattern.

Solutions below $10^5$ : $$1,2,4,5,10,13,20,26,37,52,65,74,130,148,185,260,370,463,481,740,926,962,1852,1924,2315,2405,4630,4810,6019,9260,9620,12038,17131,24076,30095,34262,60190,68524,85655$$

The list of solutions is https://oeis.org/A064383

Below $10^6$ , we have the additional solutions $$120380,171310,222703,342620,445406,890812$$ I have no clue which structure might be behind that.

According to Gardiner , what was the Difficulty rating for $(***)$ ??

Seems to be "|Unsolved Problem In Number Theory|" level , while the $n$ are factors of $451337463\cdots$ which are somehow connected to $e$ , naturally !!

He doesn't mention $()$ per se, but does say 'make sure that you tackle all the exercises marked with a single asterisk $()$. (Harder exercises, which you may well find too difficult on a first reading, are marked with a double asterisk $()$.)'  Examples of $()$ problems are 'Prove that a real number written as a decimal is equal to a rational number if and only if the decimal eventually recurs' and 'Complete the factorisation $x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(...)$'.  This is the only $(*)$ problem.

This question is similar to: Recurrence relations and divisibility. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found using an Approach0 search. Note that there are quite a few other duplicates on this site, e.g., ...

(cont.) Recurrence Relation and Divisibility, When is $u_n$ defined by $u_1=1,u_n=(n-1)u_{n-1}+1$ divisible by $n$?, Let $a_1=1, a_n=(n-1)a_{n-1}+1,n\ge 2.$ Find $n$ such that $n|a_n.$, etc. In addition, there are also multiple AoPS threads, e.g., Sequence (note its Post #$5$ says it's an "Unsolved problem", with a reference to "R. K. Guy, Unsolved Problems in Number Theory, $3$rd ed., Springer-Verlag, $2004$, B$43$), ...

(cont.) Recurrence Relation Divisibility, Recurrence relation problem from Gardiner's Handbook, An Intresting problem on recurrence (although this currently has no replies of any sort), etc.

@JohnOmielan Many thanks for the comments - I had looked to see if it was already posed but obviously not hard enough.  So, just to check what your (and others who read this) views are - this is an unsolved problem, i.e. the result in the post below is not a solution as it moves the problem onto another, i.e. find when $n$ divides the sum?

@John1970 You're welcome for the comments. My relatively brief look though the various questions and answers does indicate that it's a currently unsolved problem. Also, as you state, the answer below is not a full solution but, rather, one which transforms your problem into a different one, which is also unsolved (i.e., doesn't have a closed form).

Not an answer but too long for a comment, this is an explanation for why, as @ChrisLewis pointed out,

$$n\mathrel{|}u_n \iff n\mathrel{|}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^kk!$$

We have $u_n=(n-1)u_{n-1}+1$, therefore
\begin{align*}
u_n&\equiv 1-u_{n-1} \pmod{n} \\
u_{n-1}&= (n-2)u_{n-2}+1\equiv1-2u_{n-2}\pmod{n} \\
\vdots \\
u_{n-k}&\equiv 1-(k+1)u_{n-(k+1)}\pmod{n}
\end{align*}
So now, substituting,
\begin{align*}
 u_n& \equiv_n1-u_{n-1} \\
 & \equiv_n 1-(1-2u_{n-2}) \\
 & \equiv_n 1-(1-2(1-3u_{n-3})) \\
 & \equiv_n 1-(1-2(1-3(\dots(1-(n-1)u_1)\dots) \\
 & \equiv_n 1-(1-2(1-3(\dots(1-(n-1))\dots) \\
 & =0!-1!+2!-3!+\dots+(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)! \\
\end{align*}
Where the last equality can be easily proven by induction.
This simplifies the problem a bit, since now we have to look to an explicit sequence. I hope this helps!
